# Heroku: Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In heroku app log I get:

```
2011-11-25T15:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/execjs
etect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a li
 (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

Are execjs and therubyracer gems needed to run rails 3.1 app on heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the error message I'm guessing this is a Rails 3.1 on the old stack, called Bamboo.

Heroku recommends the cedar stack for Rails 3.1 and they have a tutorial [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar) on how to get that going.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using the heroku cedar stack and not bamboo.

Answer (score 1):

Install JavaScript runtime environment in your systems by using following steps, as this is best way to solve the issue:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.1.31.tar.gz
tar xfv node-v0.1.31.tar.gz
cd node-v0.1.31
./configure
make
make install
```